# Javscript to show form fields editable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created two extra html form fields and when we fetch data using requestID then all form fields disabled including that fields i created so i want help that how i will show all forms fields disabled excluding that two fields:here is the code 
for all fields disabled

```
$('#FirstSection').find('input, textarea, button, select').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
$('input[type="text"], input[type="checkbox"], input[type="email"], input[type="number"], textarea, select').prop("disabled", true);
$('input[type="text"], input[type="checkbox"], input[type="email"], input[type="number"], textarea, select').attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

The two fields that i created are textarea fields:

```
<div class="col-md-8">
    <textarea name="DescribeChanges" id="RevisionChanges" class="form-control"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="col-md-8">
    <textarea name="RevisionReason" id="RevisionDiv" class="form-control"></textarea>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 function Retrieve(requestID) {
    var getItemsUrl = "/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('" + ListName + "')/items?$select=ID,Title,&$filter=(ID eq " + requestID + ")";
var promise = $.ajax({
    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + getItemsUrl,
    type: "GET",
    headers: {
        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
    },
    success: function (data) {

        console.log(data.d.results);


        if (data.d.results.length > 0) {
            var ArrayRetrieved = data.d.results[0];
            console.log(ArrayRetrieved);
            //LICENSES
            $("#idF").val(ArrayRetrieved.ID); //You have to add this HIDDEN field to your HTML : <span name="ID" type="text" id="idF" style="display:none" />
            $("#RevisionChanges").html(ArrayRetrieved.Title); // Title is the internal name of your column

 }
    },
        error: function (error) {
        console.log("Error on Retrieve");
        console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
    }
});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [not](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)-selector:

```
[...] , textarea:not("#RevisionChanges,#RevisionDiv") [...]
```